# Toolbar Button for Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extensions

anybody know any way of creating/putting an icon/button in google chrome's toolbar that will open its built-in Developer Tools?

i know there are keyboard shortcut options, menu bar options, secondary-clicking within webpage option, & the 3lined icon at the far right of chrome's toolbar. but i'm wanting a simple button, single click, to open it.

i've also scoured google chrome extensions & have come up empty.

thanks.